# Is there a way I can integrate a volley inside the requestLocationUpdates()?

Tags: android, service, background-service

How can I integrate volley on this method? I'm new to android and having a hard time, this is a part of a service class and I want to insert a volley for it to be activated together with a button click.. please help me

```
public void requestLocationUpdates() { 
    Common.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class));
    if (mLocation != null)
        insertdata();
    try {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback ,Looper.myLooper());
    }catch (SecurityException ex)
    {
        Log.e("Err1", "Lost location permission.Could not request it "+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that method inside a Service class?

Comment: yes it is a method inside a class, and my goal is to integrate that insert data so that it will be included in the looper.. I forgot to delete that if part.. I apologize for my noobness.. :)